fix the pdf flash with many pages when using react-pdf
I am using react-pdf version 9.0.1 to show latex compiled pdf in react(version 18) project, and working with the flash issue when scale pdf followed by this issue https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/875 and found a demo https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-pdf-prevent-flash-with-scale-nse51l?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A23%2C28.
Then I changed my code and it look like fine with a small pdf file. But it become slow with a large pdf with more than 500 pages. This is my pdf rendered code look like:
const renderPages = (totalPageNum: number | undefined) => {
      if (!totalPageNum || totalPageNum < 1) return;
      const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
      for (let curPageNo = 1; curPageNo <= totalPageNum; curPageNo++) {
        let legacyRenderedKey = curPageNo + "@" + projAttribute.legacyPdfScale;
        let legacyPage = legacyRendered?.get(legacyRenderedKey);
        if (legacyPage && projAttribute.legacyPdfScale && projAttribute.legacyPdfScale !== projAttribute.pdfScale) {
          // if the new page did not rendered
          // show the legacy page
          // https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/875
          tagList.push(
            <Page
              key={legacyRenderedKey}
              className={styles.reactPdfPagePrevPage}
              scale={projAttribute.legacyPdfScale}
              pageNumber={curPageNo}
            >
              {curPdfPosition && viewport ? (
                <Highlight
                  position={curPdfPosition}
                  pageNumber={curPageNo}
                  viewport={viewport}
                ></Highlight>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
            </Page>
          );
        }
        tagList.push(
          <Page
            key={curPageNo + "@" + projAttribute.pdfScale}
            className={styles.pdfPage}
            scale={projAttribute.pdfScale}
            onLoad={handlePageChange}
            canvasRef={(element) => updateRefArray(curPageNo, element)}
            onChange={handlePageChange}
            onRenderSuccess={(page: PageCallback) => {
              handlePageRenderSuccess(page, curPageNo, legacyRenderedKey);
            }}
            pageNumber={curPageNo}
          >
            {curPdfPosition && viewport ? (
              <Highlight
                position={curPdfPosition}
                pageNumber={curPageNo}
                viewport={viewport}
              ></Highlight>
            ) : (
              <div></div>
            )}
          </Page>
        );
      }
      return tagList;
    };

I store a map to remember the previous pdf and new pdf render status. if the legacy pdf exists, shows legacy page, if legacy page not exists, show the newer one. the problem is that the scale is so slow and will take >5s to give a new page render response. and the pdf scroll position also changed and could not keep the original position.
it look like hard to fixed it because the scale will rerender all the pdf page that hard to complete in a short time.
is it possible to avoid the pdf render latency? what should I do to handle the large pdf to make the zoom smooth? BTW, this is my full code of the pdf render component:
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf";
import styles from "./MemoizedPDFPreview.module.css";
import {
  DocumentCallback,
  Options,
  PageCallback,
} from "react-pdf/dist/cjs/shared/types";
import { AppState } from "@/redux/types/AppState";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { ProjAttribute } from "@/model/proj/config/ProjAttribute";
import { PdfPosition } from "@/model/proj/pdf/PdfPosition";
import { ProjInfo } from "@/model/proj/ProjInfo";
import Highlight from "../feat/highlight/Highlight";
import { PageViewport } from "pdfjs-dist";
import { readConfig } from "@/config/app/config-reader";
import { goPage } from "./PDFPreviewHandle";

interface PDFPreviewProps {
  curPdfUrl: string;
  projId: string;
  options: Options;
  viewModel: string;
  setPageNum: (page: number) => void;
  setCurPageNum: (page: number) => void;
}

const MemoizedPDFPreview: React.FC<PDFPreviewProps> = React.memo(
  ({
    curPdfUrl,
    projId,
    options,
    viewModel = "default",
    setPageNum,
    setCurPageNum,
  }) => {
    const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState<number>();
    let pdfScaleKey = "pdf:scale:" + projId;
    let cachedScale = Number(localStorage.getItem(pdfScaleKey));
    const [projAttribute, setProjAttribute] = useState<ProjAttribute>({
      pdfScale: cachedScale,
      legacyPdfScale: cachedScale,
    });
    const [curProjInfo, setCurProjInfo] = useState<ProjInfo>();
    const [viewport, setViewport] = useState<PageViewport>();
    const { projAttr, pdfFocus, projInfo } = useSelector(
      (state: AppState) => state.proj
    );
    const [curPdfPosition, setCurPdfPosition] = useState<PdfPosition[]>();
    const canvasArray = useRef<
      Array<React.MutableRefObject<HTMLCanvasElement | null>>
    >([]);
    const [legacyRendered, setLegacyRendered] = useState<Map<string, boolean>>(
      new Map<string, boolean>()
    );

    React.useEffect(() => {
      setCurProjInfo(projInfo);
    }, [projInfo]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (projAttr.pdfScale === 1 && cachedScale) {
        return;
      }
      setProjAttribute(projAttr);
    }, [projAttr, cachedScale]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (pdfFocus && pdfFocus.length > 0) {
        let pageNum = pdfFocus[0].page;
        setCurPdfPosition(pdfFocus);
        localStorage.setItem(
          readConfig("pdfCurPage") + curProjInfo?.main.project_id,
          pageNum.toString()
        );
        goPage(pageNum);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setCurPdfPosition([]);
        }, 5000);
      }
    }, [pdfFocus]);

    const updateRefArray = (
      index: number,
      element: HTMLCanvasElement | null
    ) => {
      if (element) {
        canvasArray.current[index] = { current: element };
      }
    };

    const handlePageChange = (page: any) => {};

    var pageObserve = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
        entries.forEach((item: IntersectionObserverEntry) => {
          if (item.intersectionRatio > 0) {
            let dataPage = item.target.getAttribute("data-page-number");
            // pass the current page to parent component
            setCurPageNum(Number(dataPage));
            if (!dataPage) return;
            localStorage.setItem(
              readConfig("pdfCurPage") + projId,
              dataPage.toString()
            );
          }
        });
      },
      {
        threshold: 0,
      }
    );

    const handlePageRenderSuccess = (
      page: PageCallback,
      curPage: number,
      legacyRenderedKey: string
    ) => {
      let elements = document.querySelectorAll(`.${styles.pdfPage}`);
      if (elements && elements.length > 0) {
        elements.forEach((box) => pageObserve.observe(box));
        restorePdfPosition();
      }
      let viewport: PageViewport = page.getViewport({ scale: cachedScale });
      setViewport(viewport);
      // remove legacy indicator
      // legacyRendered.delete(legacyRenderedKey);
      let prev = legacyRendered;
      prev?.delete(legacyRenderedKey);
      setLegacyRendered(prev);
      // insert new indicator
      let newRenderedKey = curPage + "@" + projAttribute.pdfScale;
      prev?.set(newRenderedKey, true);
      setLegacyRendered(prev);
    };

    const restorePdfPosition = () => {
      const key = readConfig("pdfScrollKey") + projId;
      const scrollPosition = localStorage.getItem(key);
      if (scrollPosition) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const pdfContainerDiv = document.getElementById("pdfContainer");
          if (pdfContainerDiv) {
            let scroll = parseInt(scrollPosition);
            pdfContainerDiv.scrollTop = scroll;
          }
        }, 0);
      }
    };

    const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (pdf: DocumentCallback) => {
      const { numPages } = pdf;
      setNumPages(numPages);
      setPageNum(numPages);
    };

    const getDynStyles = (viewModel: string) => {
      switch (viewModel) {
        case "default":
          return styles.previewBody;
        case "fullscreen":
          return styles.previewFsBody;
        default:
          return styles.previewBody;
      }
    };

    const renderPages = (totalPageNum: number | undefined) => {
      if (!totalPageNum || totalPageNum < 1) return;
      const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
      for (let curPageNo = 1; curPageNo <= totalPageNum; curPageNo++) {
        let legacyRenderedKey = curPageNo + "@" + projAttribute.legacyPdfScale;
        let legacyPage = legacyRendered?.get(legacyRenderedKey);
        if (legacyPage && projAttribute.legacyPdfScale && projAttribute.legacyPdfScale !== projAttribute.pdfScale) {
          // if the new page did not rendered
          // show the legacy page
          // https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/875
          tagList.push(
            <Page
              key={legacyRenderedKey}
              className={styles.reactPdfPagePrevPage}
              scale={projAttribute.legacyPdfScale}
              pageNumber={curPageNo}
            >
              {curPdfPosition && viewport ? (
                <Highlight
                  position={curPdfPosition}
                  pageNumber={curPageNo}
                  viewport={viewport}
                ></Highlight>
              ) : (
                <div></div>
              )}
            </Page>
          );
        }
        tagList.push(
          <Page
            key={curPageNo + "@" + projAttribute.pdfScale}
            className={styles.pdfPage}
            scale={projAttribute.pdfScale}
            onLoad={handlePageChange}
            canvasRef={(element) => updateRefArray(curPageNo, element)}
            onChange={handlePageChange}
            onRenderSuccess={(page: PageCallback) => {
              handlePageRenderSuccess(page, curPageNo, legacyRenderedKey);
            }}
            pageNumber={curPageNo}
          >
            {curPdfPosition && viewport ? (
              <Highlight
                position={curPdfPosition}
                pageNumber={curPageNo}
                viewport={viewport}
              ></Highlight>
            ) : (
              <div></div>
            )}
          </Page>
        );
      }
      return tagList;
    };

    const handlePdfScroll = (e: React.UIEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
      const scrollTop = e.currentTarget.scrollTop;
      const key = readConfig("pdfScrollKey") + projId;
      localStorage.setItem(key, scrollTop.toString());
    };

    /**
     * Open pdf's link in the browser new tab
     * https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/645
     * @param e
     */
    const openPdfUrlLink = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ((e.target as HTMLElement).tagName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
        window.open((e.target as HTMLAnchorElement).href);
      }
    };

    return (
      <div
        id="pdfContainer"
        className={getDynStyles(viewModel)}
        onClick={openPdfUrlLink}
        onScroll={(e) => handlePdfScroll(e)}
      >
        <Document
          options={options}
          file={curPdfUrl}
          onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
          {renderPages(numPages)}
        </Document>
      </div>
    );
  },
  (prevProps, nextProps) => {
    let arePropsEqual = prevProps.curPdfUrl === nextProps.curPdfUrl;
    return arePropsEqual;
  }
);

export default MemoizedPDFPreview;

